# Where do I place the paste_block_drop option in tinymce?

Tags: plugins, tinymce, wysiwyg

I am wanted to disable the drag and dropping of images within our textarea of the WYSIWYG and only allow for images to uploaded.

We do have the 'paste' plugin for tinymce and i have found this code within the plugin:

```
// Block all drag/drop events
    if (editor.paste_block_drop) {
        editor.on('dragend dragover draggesture dragdrop drop drag', function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            e.stopPropagation();
        });
    }
```

But I am not sure in what js file i am to call paste_block_drop.  I know this will do the trick.

oh and by the way, we are using Angular/ui-tinymce.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

paste_block_drop is a parameter that you set along with other tinymce parameters like (theme, height and selector) when initilizing your editor (see example [here](https://www.tinymce.com/docs/demo/full-featured/)).

It is after initialization accessible through

```
tinymce.activeEditor.settings.paste_block_drop
```

or

```
tinymce.activeEditor.getParam('paste_block_drop')
```

The code snippet you are using refers to `editor.paste_block_drop` which does not get set by tinymce itself. You may search your plugin for a pieve of code that explicitly sets `editor.paste_block_drop` before.
I would suggest to use `editor.getParam('paste_block_drop')` .

Comment: Thanks, I will be looking into this. @thariama